Probability for a random variable to exceed its expectation
Let $X$ be a real random variable, defined on some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{T},\mathbb{P})$, with finite expectation $\mathbb{E}(X)$.
I don't make any other assumption.
I am convinced that $\mathbb{P}\left(X\geqslant\mathbb{E}(X)\right)>0$ (that is : non zero), but I don't see how to prove it rigorously.
Thanks in advance for any hint / help ...

Also there is no better absolute bound.  Consider a random variable which takes value $n$ with probability $1/n$ and $0$ otherwise, for large $n$.

@MichaelLugo: Similarly, you can't set a (useful) upper bound, because the delta distribution always returns exactly its expected value.

If $\mathbb P\big\{X\geq \mathbb E[X]\big\}=0$, then $\mathbb P\big\{X<\mathbb E[X]\big\}=1$. Therefore, $$X<\mathbb E[X]\quad  \text{a.s.},$$ and thus, $$\mathbb E[X]<\mathbb E\big[\mathbb E[X]\big]=\mathbb E[X],$$ which is a contradiction.

Abbreviate $\mu:=\Bbb E[X]$.
Suppose $\Bbb P\left(X\ge \mu\right)=0$. Then $\mu-X$ is a non-negative random variable with mean $0$. By Markov's inequality
$$
\Bbb P(\mu-X> 1/n)\le{\Bbb E[\mu-X]\over1/n}={\mu-\mu\over 1/n}=0
$$
for each positive integer $n$. It follows that  $\mu-X=0$ a.s.; that is, $\Bbb P(X=\mu) =1$.
In short, apart from the degenerate case in which $X$ is a.s. constant, both $\Bbb P(X>\mu)$ (and by the same token $\Bbb P(X<\mu)$) must be strictly positive.

Directly from the definition:
Suppose for a contradiction that $\mathbb{P}[X\geq \mathbb{E}[X]]=0$. Since the probability of $X$ exceeding its expectation is zero this is equal to
$$\mathbb{E}[X] =\int_\Omega X dp = \int_{\{X:X<\mathbb{E}[X]\}} X dP$$
moreover we know the probability of the event $\{X<\mathbb{E}[X]\}$ is 1 since it is the complement of the event we are interested in, hence we can bound this integral in the following way:
$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_{\{X:X<\mathbb{E}[X]\}} X dP< \mathbb{E}[X]\int_{\{X:X<\mathbb{E}[X]\}}  dP= \mathbb{E}[X]$$
This boils down to this question about strict monotonocity
